# Learning Spring / Java: How To Inject Spring Bean

Tags: java, spring

I am learning Spring and Java at the same time.  I am working on my application context.  Here is one of my beans:

```
package com.example.app.context;

@Configuration
public class ApplicationContextConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ComboPooledDataSource comboPooledDataSource() {
        // ... setup pool here
        return pool;
    }
}
```

Now I want to use this bean:

```
package com.example.db.queries;

import javax.inject.Inject;

public class DatabaseQueries {

    @Inject private ComboPooledDataSource comboPooledDataSource;

    public static List<Records> getData() {
        Connection connection = comboPooledDataSource.getConnection();
        // ... create sql query and execute 
}
```

But I get this error at compile time:

```
[ERROR] non-static variable comboPooledDataSource cannot be referenced from a static context
```

How do I access this bean?

Thanks in advance, and please remember, I'm learning!

Comment: This has nothing to do with Spring or injection.

Comment: The error tells your everything. Your field is an instance field. Your method is static.

Comment: Ok thanks Brian, can you please help me out figure out what this is about?

Comment: Simply searching for that error will being up numerous questions on SO, I've marked this as a duplicate of one of them.

Comment: @DavidWilliams Your method is static and trying to access a non static object.

Comment: But just for the record, this is the right way to inject???????

Comment: @DavidWilliams - Instead of using class for configuration, I prefer defining beans in XML file.

Comment: Hi Sachin, thanks, I appreciate that, however I am trying to move it out of xml due to some feedback in a code review :)

Comment: Though when I get here:  `public class DatabaseQuery {

    @Inject private ComboPooledDataSource comboPooledDataSource;

    private Connection getConnection() {
        try {
            return comboPooledDataSource.getConnection();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
`  its a null pointer exception.  How do I get at this bean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method `getData()` ist static. when working with Spring or in generally with Dependency Injection you use static methods much less than you might used to be. Make it non-static. When ever you need to to use your DatabaseQueries, you inject it again.

```java
@Component
public class DatabaseQueries {

@Inject 
private ComboPooledDataSource comboPooledDataSource;

public List<Records> getData() {
    Connection connection = comboPooledDataSource.getConnection();
    // ... create sql query and execute 
}
```

And the usage:

```
@Component
public class AnotherBean{

    @Inject 
    private DatabaseQueries queries;

    public void doSomething {
        List<Records> data = queries.getData();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1. I would like to add the fact that all beans created by Spring are by default singletons.

Comment: @adarshr We have to be careful. They are singleton in the Spring context.

Comment: true, not the best sample. be careful the the datasource.

Comment: Speaking of contexts, @Sotirios, how would I get at this bean in a unit test?  How would I init Spring context in a test?

Comment: @DavidWilliams You're better off googling that. You can use `@ContextConfiguration` with a `SpringJUnit4RunnerClassRunner`.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a Java error than a Spring one.

You need to declare the method getData() as not static.

Comment: If OP declares `ComboPooledDataSource` as static, it becomes a Spring problem because `@Inject` won't work, as is.